# SQL Insert/Update using Merge for multiple scenarios

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-merge

I have 4 scenarios to cover so I am using the below Merge query in SQL Server 2016. Using Merge query, scenarios 1,2,3 work but scenario 4 does not work. Can someone please help?
also, I am ok to use other approaches as well like JOINS if it covers all 4 scenarios.

**Please note** Source table i.e. temp_Wrike_Kimble can have 1 or many records which need to be updated/insert into target table (Wrike_Task_Kimble_Log)

Link: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=79f0e083c27f602f307f24010c3639ff&hide=4)

```
--Create a target table
CREATE TABLE Wrike_Task_Kimble_Log
(
   Taskid varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   Wrike_Update_Task_URL varchar(max),
   ActualMargin float,
   BudgetMargin float,
   IsProcessed bit default 0,
   Rootpid varchar(50)
) 


--Create source table
CREATE TABLE temp_Wrike_Kimble
(
   Taskid varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   Wrike_Update_Task_URL varchar(max),
   ActualMargin float,
   BudgetMargin float,
   IsProcessed bit default 0,
   Rootpid varchar(50)
)
```

**Merge Query:**

```
MERGE Wrike_Task_Kimble_Log AS TARGET
USING temp_Wrike_Kimble AS SOURCE 
ON (TARGET.TaskId = SOURCE.TaskId)

WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.Rootpid <> SOURCE.Rootpid AND TARGET.IsProcessed = SOURCE.IsProcessed 
THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.Rootpid = SOURCE.Rootpid

--When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,BudgetMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid) 
VALUES (SOURCE.TaskId, SOURCE.Wrike_Update_Task_URL,SOURCE.ActualMargin,SOURCE.BudgetMargin,SOURCE.IsProcessed,SOURCE.rootpid)

OUTPUT $action, 


INSERTED.TaskId AS TargetTaskId, 
INSERTED.Wrike_Update_Task_URL AS TargetWrike_Update_Task_URL,
INSERTED.ActualMargin AS TargetActualMargin, 
INSERTED.BudgetMargin AS TargetBudgetMargin,
INSERTED.IsProcessed AS TargetIsProcessed,
INSERTED.Rootpid AS TargetRootpid;



SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

**Scenario 1:** If in the first run, the record was not processed in target as (IsProcessed= 0), then in next run for the same record, only UPDATE the rootpid of target table to 'test2'

```
    --Insert records into the target table
    INSERT INTO Wrike_Task_Kimble_Log (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,BudgetMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid)
    VALUES
     ('T1',NULL,10,5,0,'test1')

--Insert records into the source table
INSERT INTO temp_Wrike_Kimble (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,BudgetMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid)
VALUES
   ('T1',NULL,10,5,0,'test2')
```

**Scenario2:**  If a record is already successfully processed in target (IsProcessed= 1), then in the next run, the record having the same (TaskId AND ActualMargin AND BudgetMargin) will be ignored i.e. neither UPDATE / INSERT in the target table

```
--Insert records into target table
INSERT INTO Wrike_Task_Kimble_Log (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,BudgetMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid)
VALUES
 ('T1','www.url',10,5,1,'test1')


--Insert records into source table
INSERT INTO temp_Wrike_Kimble (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid)
VALUES
   ('T1',NULL,10,5,0,'test2')
```

**Scenario3:** If a record is new (TaskId) i.e. which does not exist in Target then simply INSERT new record from Source to Target.

```
--Insert records into target table
INSERT INTO Wrike_Task_Kimble_Log (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,BudgetMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid)
VALUES
 ('T1','www.url',10,5,1,'test1')


--Insert records into source table
INSERT INTO temp_Wrike_Kimble (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,BudgetMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid)
VALUES
  ('T2',NULL,90,80,0,'test1')
```

**Scenario4:**  If for a TaksId which is already processed in Target (IsProcessed= 1), but its (ActualMargin OR BudgetMargin) is changed in Source table, then INSERT it as new record from Source to Target

```
--Insert records into target table
INSERT INTO Wrike_Task_Kimble_Log (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,BudgetMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid)
VALUES
 ('T1','www.url',10,5,1,'test1')


--Insert records into source table
INSERT INTO temp_Wrike_Kimble (TaskId,Wrike_Update_Task_URL,ActualMargin,BudgetMargin,IsProcessed,Rootpid)
VALUES
 ('T1',NULL,10,2,0,'test2')
```

Comment: I would advise against using MERGE for even mildly complex logic like this. At the least it will be nightmarish to maintain. This would be clearer as a set of updates and inserts. You might just need to be careful about the order you look for the different scenarios to avoid double processing

Comment: @JamesCasey Agree! Using MERGE is tricky. But I couldn't find any other way to get handle all scenarios and so in my post I have mentioned as well I am open with other approaches as well like JOINS

Comment: Your scenario 4 would insert an additional record with the same taskid? How does that then affect future runs, we would match against both? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, Scenario4 would insert an additional record in Target with the same taskid if in Source table we have different ActualMargin OR BudgetMargin for the same taskid. 
In the future let's say if values for any of these 2 column changes then again new row should be inserted. 
Also if you see sample data, of scenario4, every time a new record is inserted in Target for the same taskid it will have a unique rootpid value i.e. test2, test3, and so on. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: But once you have a new record with a different ActualMargin, say, then *every* future run with differ from one of the two records if we are only matching on TaskId. So it sounds like we should be comparing to the latest record only. Can the rootpid values be relied on to always increase for a given taskid?

Comment: That's correct, if only there is a change in any of the 2 Margin columns for already existing TaskId then only we will compare with the latest record i.e. recently processed record of that TaskId. Regarding Rootpid, I will say, every time the process/query is executed it will have a new unique value in the Source table which will be updated/inserted in Target for rows depending on the 4 scenarios.

Comment: You'll need some way to identify the latest record to know what to compare to. Even if you have an incrementing number on the end of the rootpid as per the test data you have shown, it might be problematic since its a VARCHAR field and so test10 would come before test2. You could maybe add an identity column to the target, or a date column (perhaps one that defaults to GETDATE())